# Why is Tangelo Island named as such?

Tags: pokemon

In Pokémon, there's an island named [Tangelo Island](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Tangelo_Island). However, it's Japanese name translates to Bontan Island. There is another fruit called Pomelo, which in Japanese is said Buntan. Is this some pun on the name of the fruit? Also, Tangelo and Pomelo are quite different fruits:
[image: Tangelo]
Tangelo ^
[image: Pomelo]
Pomelo ^

Which one of these, if any, is grown there?

Comment: The tangelo is actually a hybrid of pomelo and another fruit. Just FIY, maybe it has something to do with the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tangelo Island is situated in the [Orange Archipelago](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Orange_Archipelago), a series of islands in the Pokémon world, located south of the Kanto region. Each of these islands is tropical and generally warm, and many of them are named after fruits—particularly oranges (its namesake) and other citrus fruits:

- Valencia Island ([Valencia oranges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valencia_orange))
- Tangelo Island (the [tangelo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangelo))
- Mikan Island (the Japanese name for [satsuma oranges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citrus_unshiu))
- Sunburst Island ([sunburst tangerines](http://www.urbanharvest.org/advice/fruitgardening/fruitvarieties/tangerinemandarinsatsuma.html))
- Mandarin Island, North and South ([Mandarin oranges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandarin_orange))
- Kinnow Island (the [kinnow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinnow))
- Navel Island ([navel oranges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navel_orange#Navel_oranges))
- Seven Grapefruit Islands (the [grapefruit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapefruit))
- Golden Islands (possibly the [Shonan Gold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shonan_Gold))
- Murcott Island (a [type of tangor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangor))
- Trovita Island (a type of navel orange)
- Fairchild Island (the [Fairchild mango](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairchild_(mango)))
- Shamouti Island (another name for the [Jaffa orange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaffa_orange))
- Ascorbia Island (named after [ascorbic acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascorbic_acid), a common acid in citrus fruits)
- Butwal Island (the Butwal lemon<sup>(unable to find a link on this)</sup>)
- Kumquat Island (the [kumquat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumquat))
- Rind Island (another name for a fruit [peel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peel_(fruit)))
- Pummelo Island (alternate spelling of [pomelo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomelo))
- Tarroco Island (a misspelling of "tarocco", a [variation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarocco#Tarocco) of the [blood orange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarocco))
- Hamlin Island (the [Hamlin orange](http://www.ultimatecitrus.com/Story/varieties/hamlin.html))

*(Note: All of the above islands also have Japanese names, such as "[Bontan Island](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Tangelo_Island)" that you pointed out, which are also largely related to citrus and citrus fruits. Additionally, there are a handful of unnamed islands, and a few named after the basic elements as well.)*

[Pinkan Island](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pinkan_Island) is another island in this area, whose name is derived from the Japanese word for "citrus" (柑 *kan*), and which grows berries by the name of [Pinkan Berries](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pinkan_Berry).

[image: Some images of Pokémon and berries on Pinkan Island]

However, aside from Pinkan Island, none of the others appear to grow fruits that are related to their name. It does not appear as if Tangelo grows tangelos and Navel Island grows navel oranges, for example. There may be fruits growing on these islands, like the Pinkan Berry, but there is not a trend for each of the islands that has determined the names of the islands.

In fact, like you pointed out, the Japanese and English names often diverge quite significantly; the reason they are able to do this is that each island is not specifically named after what grows there.